# How to use beautiful soup findAll to find a class if it has spaces in it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a freakin' noob. So I used beautiful soup to parse some HTML and now have this content

< tr >content<\tr>

So I use soup.findAll('tr') to try to get to content. But the problem is that since < tr > has spaces between the <> then soup.findAll('tr') can't reach it.

Comment: I had a go at editing but there's no way for me to know what you're asking at the end sorry.

Comment: you could  create minimal working example so we could easily run it and see problem.

Comment: if you know that there is `< tr` then you could simply replace `< tr` with `<tr` in `HTML` before you use `BeautifulSoup(HTML)` - `HTML` is only string.

Comment: Sorry fellas! I'm feeling particularly crappy at English today. @furas I wondered if I can do that, but I used requests to grab HTML from a webpage and the HTML won't be a string so I haven't been able to use any fancy string processing techniques.

Comment: `requests` returns HTML as string - `response.text` - or bytes - `response.content` - and you can do `html = response.text.replace("< tr", "<tr")`

Comment: That works for getting rid of the space but for some reason soup.findAll('tr') can't find the newly changed <tr>